# Multiple records on one row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas data frame that stores multiple records on the same row as below

| id1 | id2 | id3 | valueA1 | valueA2 | valueA3 | valueB1 | valueB2 | valueB3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | X | Y | Z | A | B | C |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | P | Q | U | S | V | M |

I am looking for a generic (an arbitrary number of IDs and and associated values) way to stack these records such that I have

| id | valueA | valueB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | A |
| 2 | Y | B |
| 3 | Z | C |
| 2 | P | S |
| 1 | Q | V |
| 3 | U | M |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.lreshape(df, {
    'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 
    'valueA': ['valueA1', 'valueA2', 'valueA3'], 
    'valueB': ['valueB1', 'valueB2', 'valueB3']})
```

---

Or:

```
pd.lreshape(df, {
    'id': df.filter(like='id').columns.tolist(), 
    'valueA': df.filter(like='valueA').columns.tolist(), 
    'valueB': df.filter(like='valueB').columns.tolist()})
```

---

Output:

```
   id valueA valueB
0   1      X      A
1   2      P      S
2   2      Y      B
3   1      Q      V
4   3      Z      C
5   3      U      M
```

Comment: Gorgeous stuff, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a MultiIndex and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
(df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract('(.*)(\d+)$')),
             axis=1)
 .stack()
 #.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None) # optional
)
```

Output:

```
0    id valueA valueB
  1                  
0 1   1      X      A
  2   2      Y      B
  3   3      Z      C
1 1   2      P      S
  2   1      Q      V
  3   3      U      M
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `pd.wide_to_long()`

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                      i='index',j='t',
                      stubnames=['id','valueA','valueB'],
                      suffix=r'.*')
                      .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   id valueA valueB
0   1      X      A
1   2      P      S
2   2      Y      B
3   1      Q      V
4   3      Z      C
5   3      U      M
```